# Definition of a fractional ideal sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Wikipedia, in the article "divisor", defines a **fractional ideal sheaf** to be a sub-$\mathscr O_X$-module of the sheaf of rational functions $M_X$.

However, Kempf's book *Algebraic Varieties* defines in page 63 the same notion with the additional requirement that the sheaf be **coherent**. Is that a true difference? What does it stem from? And why does either of these definitions provide an analog for the usual invertible ideals, as in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal)?

Comment: This is certainly a mistake in the Wikipedia article. For example, the sheaf of rational function $M_X$ is not a fractional ideal. But we can also find proper sub-$\mathscr{O}_X$-modules of $M_X$ which aren't coherent (because they are not locally finitely generated, or because they are not quasi-coherent ! like the extension by zero of $\mathscr{O}_U$ for an open subset $U\subset X$).

Answer (score 1):

A fractional ideal sheaf is a subsheaf of the sheaf of total quotient rings $\mathcal{K}_X$ which is a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Among fractional ideal sheaves, (generalized) divisors are those which are nondegenerate and reflexive as $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.

See this paper by Harstshorne for a detailed exposition:

R. Hartshorne, [*Generalized divisors on Gorenstein schemes*](http://access.portico.org/Portico/#!journalAUSimpleView/tab=PDF?cs=ISSN_09203036?ct=E-Journal%20Content?auId=ark:/27927/pgg197h2mgc), K-Theory v. 8, n. 3 (May, 1994): 287-339